# Pickle won't save just the object instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, pickle

I'm working with text classification using NLTK and since it would take a long time to re-train my classifier everytime I want to use it I've been trying to use pickle to save an instance of the classifier that I can just call up later.

My code looks like this:

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
filehandler = open("class.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump( classifier, filehandler )
filehandler.close()
```

However, when I pull up the classifier in another program:

```
classifier = pickle.load(open("class.pickle","rb"))
```

and run the program, it doesn't just open the classifier object, but it runs the entire file as well, and in doing so retrains everything and runs code that doesn't need to be run (such as print statements).

edit: It seems the problem was I was also importing another function from the file I created my classifier in. I moved this function to my new file and re-ran it and it works fine now.

Comment: Huh. What happens if you have `classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier` and then do `classifier.train(training_set)` on another line, then pickle dump `classifier` as you currently do? I wouldn't expect pickle to work the way you describe, I'm curious as to why this happens.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I believe .train() is what actually returns the trained classifier object, so if I don't have that on the end then the I have a different object entirely. (And it breaks some methods later on in the code as well)

Comment: Which NLTK version are you using? Pickling should work with the latest version, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/514

Comment: Try upgrading your NLTK with `pip install -U nltk`

Comment: I have the most up to date version (3.2.5). The object technically works, it just also loads a ton of unnecessary code.

Comment: I don't think it retrains. It might print some user message though.

Comment: Could you share your training set and pickle file somewhere?

Comment: From my understanding, pickle saves an instance of an object that is independent from where it was created. Yet, if I mess with the original file then my pickled object will break or run extra code. edited my post with links

Comment: When I loaded your pickle file, it didn't retrain nor print anything =(

Comment: How did you extract the features to create the `training_set`?

Comment: Yeah, it was because I was importing another function from the other file and that was what was printing and rerunning all the code for some reason. I'm blind :(

Comment: No worries! At least there's no problem with the classifier in the library ;P